# The requested PHP extension ext-iconv * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's iconv extension

Tags: php, composer-php, iconv

I am trying to install Encore in my symfony application using this this command:

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
```

i received this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-iconv * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's iconv extension.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I googled a little bit i found out that iconv extension is enabled by default and i had never issues with it so I dont know what to do. 
I am using arch linux and xampp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`php -i | grep php.ini`

then

in your php.ini

`extension=iconv.so`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I tried this before but I edited file in /opt/lampp/etc